# Do I need to use classical bits in measurement?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, measurement

I wonder if I have to add classical bits while performing measurement for a single-qubit quantum circuit. The difference to initialize the circuit is `QuantumCircuit(1)` and `QuantumCircuit(1,1)`. I noticed if I do not add the classical bit while drawing the circuit, I'm automatically assigned with a `meas` bit:
[image]

Is that the same as a classical bit? Will there be any difference when I run the two versions of the circuit on the simulator and quantum device? Thanks!

Comment: Did you use the function `measure_all()` ?

Comment: @KAJ226 Yes, I did use that in `QuantumCircuit(1)`:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **don't** need to define classical bits in your QuantumCircuit if you are going to use the function `measure_all()`.

The two scripts below (Script 1 and Script 2) are **equivalent**:

```
# Script 1
qc1 = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc1.h(0)
qc1.measure_all()
print(qc1)

        ┌───┐ ░ ┌─┐
   q_0: ┤ H ├─░─┤M├
        └───┘ ░ └╥┘
meas: 1/═════════╩═
                 0
```

```
# Script 2
qc2 = QuantumCircuit(1,1)
qc2.h(0)
qc2.measure([0],[0])
print(qc2)
     ┌───┐┌─┐
q_0: ┤ H ├┤M├
     └───┘└╥┘
c: 1/══════╩═
           0
```

You can check the result on `qasm_simulator`:

```
execute(qc1, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 1000).result().get_counts()
>>> {'0': 486, '1': 514}
```

```
execute(qc2, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 1000).result().get_counts()
>>> {'1': 468, '0': 532}
```

Thus, you **don't need to define classical bits** (cbits) in your QuantumCircuit if you are going to use `measure_all()` function.

---

**However**, you want to **avoid** doing something like:

```
# Script 3
qc3 = QuantumCircuit(1,1)
qc3.h(0)
qc3.measure_all() 
print(qc3)

        ┌───┐ ░ ┌─┐
   q_0: ┤ H ├─░─┤M├
        └───┘ ░ └╥┘
   c: 1/═════════╬═
                 ║ 
meas: 1/═════════╩═
                 0
```

You still can run the circuit, it just give you an extra cbit of '0' in your readout dictionary. That is, you would see something like:

```
execute(qc3, Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'), shots = 1000).result().get_counts()
>>>  {'0 0': 496, '1 0': 504}
```